# Very low FPS in glmak2 tests

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games

I have Threadripper 2990wx, 128GB RAM and 2x 2080TI but when I run games (CS GO FPS is 100, max FPS is 300) or when I run glmark2 tests, all numbers are low...
Example:

```
=======================================================
   glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
   OpenGL Information
   GL_VENDOR:     NVIDIA Corporation
   GL_RENDERER:   GeForce RTX 2080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
   GL_VERSION:    4.6.0 NVIDIA 410.48
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false:
FPS: 3278 FrameTime: 0.305 ms
[build] use-vbo=true:
FPS: 4112 FrameTime: 0.243 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest:
FPS: 3708 FrameTime: 0.270 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear:
FPS: 3497 FrameTime: 0.286 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap:
FPS: 3493 FrameTime: 0.286 ms
[shading] shading=gouraud:
FPS: 3472 FrameTime: 0.288 ms
[shading] shading=blinn-phong-inf:
FPS: 3571 FrameTime: 0.280 ms
[shading] shading=phong:
FPS: 3799 FrameTime: 0.263 ms
[shading] shading=cel:
FPS: 4090 FrameTime: 0.244 ms
[bump] bump-render=high-poly:
FPS: 3627 FrameTime: 0.276 ms
[bump] bump-render=normals:
FPS: 3871 FrameTime: 0.258 ms
[bump] bump-render=height:
FPS: 4112 FrameTime: 0.243 ms
[effect2d] kernel=0,1,0;1,-4,1;0,1,0;:
FPS: 3809 FrameTime: 0.263 ms
[effect2d] kernel=1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;1,1,1,1,1;:
FPS: 3633 FrameTime: 0.275 ms
[pulsar] light=false:quads=5:texture=false:
FPS: 4116 FrameTime: 0.243 ms
[desktop] blur-radius=5:effect=blur:passes=1:separable=true:windows=4:
FPS: 3006 FrameTime: 0.333 ms
[desktop] effect=shadow:windows=4:
FPS: 3382 FrameTime: 0.296 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=map:
FPS: 1953 FrameTime: 0.512 ms
[buffer] columns=200:interleave=false:update-dispersion=0.9:update-fraction=0.5:update-method=subdata:
FPS: 2333 FrameTime: 0.429 ms
```

What am I missing?